# Linking Error when trying 3D Mesh Generation from CGAL::Polyhedral_mesh_domain_with_features_3

Tags: c++, cgal

I am wishing to use CGAL to generate 3D mesh with features. I can generate the 3D mesh from CGAL::Polyhedral_mesh_domain_3 without any problems. However, when I try to create the mesh from CGAL::Polyhedral_mesh_domain_with_features_3, I get the following error:

> ```
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: 
> "CGAL::set_binary_mode(std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:      
> CGAL::Dump_c3t3<CGAL::Mesh_complex_3_in_triangulation_3<CGAL::Regular_triangulation_3<CGAL::Robust_weighted_circumcenter_filtered_traits_3<CGAL::Mesh_3::Robust_intersection_traits_3<CGAL::Epick> >, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<CGAL::Mesh_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Robust_weighted_circumcenter_filtered_traits_3<CGAL::Mesh_3::Robust_intersection_traits_3<CGAL::Epick> >, CGAL::Polyhedral_mesh_domain_with_features_3<CGAL::Mesh_3::Robust_intersection_traits_3<CGAL::Epick> ... etc
>
> "CGAL::is_ascii(std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced > from: 
> CGAL::Dump_c3t3<CGAL::Mesh_complex_3_in_triangulation_3<CGAL::Regular_triangulation_3<CGAL::Robust_weighted_circumcenter_filtered_traits_3<CGAL::Mesh_3::Robust_intersection_traits_3<CGAL::Epick> >, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<CGAL::Mesh_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Robust_weighted_circumcenter_filtered_traits_3<CGAL::Mesh_3::Robust_intersection_traits_3<CGAL::Epick> >, CGAL::Polyhedral_mesh_domain_with_features_3<CGAL::Mesh_3::Robust_intersection_traits_3<CGAL::Epick>, ... etc 
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to seeinvocation) 
> make: *** [projectV1.app/Contents/MacOS/projectV1] Error 1 
> 11:05:54: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2. 
>   Error while building/deploying project project_VCGAL (kit: Desktop Qt 5.4.2 clang 64bit) 
> When executing step "Make"
> ```

All of the other CGAL functions are compiling and working properly, it's just this one thing. I installed CGAL via homebrew/macports (both give the same error). I am not sure where I am going wrong. I would really appreciate any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this.

Typedefs:

```
typedef double Real; 
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel Kernel; 
typedef CGAL::Mesh_3::Robust_intersection_traits_3<Kernel> IGT; 
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<IGT, My_items> Polyhedron; 
typedef Polyhedron::HalfedgeDS HalfedgeDS; 
typedef CGAL::Point_3<Kernel> Point; 
using namespace std; 

//Volume Mesh 
typedef CGAL::Mesh_polyhedron_3<IGT>::Type Mesh_polyhedron; 
typedef CGAL::Polyhedral_mesh_domain_with_features_3<IGT, Polyhedron> MeshDomain; 
typedef CGAL::Mesh_triangulation_3<MeshDomain>::type Tr; 
typedef CGAL::Mesh_complex_3_in_triangulation_3<Tr,MeshDomain::Corner_index,MeshDomain::Curve_segment_index> C3T3; 
typedef CGAL::Mesh_criteria_3
```

Creating volume mesh:

```
using namespace CGAL::parameters; 
Mesh_Domain domain(mesh_Poly); 
domain.detect_features(); 
Mesh_Criteria criteria(facet_angle=30, facet_size=0.1, facet_distance=0.025, cell_radius_edge_ratio=2, cell_size=0.1); 
c3t3 = CGAL::make_mesh_3<C3T3>(domain, criteria); /* Error occurs here */
```

My linking is as follows:

```
#------------------------------------------------- 
# CGAL LIBRARY 
#------------------------------------------------- 
macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../opt/local/lib/ -lCGAL 

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../opt/local/include 
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../opt/local/include 
#------------------------------------------------- 
# CGAL CORE LIBRARY 
#------------------------------------------------- 
macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../opt/local/lib/ -lCGAL_Core.11 

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../opt/local/include 
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../opt/local/include 
#------------------------------------------------- 
# CGAL IMAGE IO LIBRARY 
#------------------------------------------------- 
macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../opt/local/lib/ -lCGAL_ImageIO 

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../opt/local/include 
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../opt/local/include 
#------------------------------------------------- 
# BOOST THREAD LIBRARY 
#------------------------------------------------- 
macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../opt/local/lib/ -lboost_thread-mt 

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../opt/local/include 
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../opt/local/include 
#------------------------------------------------- 
# BOOST SYSTEM LIBRARY 
#------------------------------------------------- 
macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../opt/local/lib/ -lboost_system-mt 

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../opt/local/include 
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../opt/local/include 
#------------------------------------------------- 
# GMP LIBRARY 
#------------------------------------------------- 
macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../opt/local/lib/ -lgmp 

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../opt/local/include 
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../opt/local/include 
#------------------------------------------------- 
# MPFR LIBRARY 
#------------------------------------------------- 
macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../opt/local/lib/ -lmpfr 

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../opt/local/include 
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../opt/local/include
```

Comment: The actual command line would be more useful than an extract from a Makefile. Probably a libstdc++ vs libc++ mismatch. Use  `nm` to look at libCGAL and see what the exact name of is_ascii is.

Comment: Ok, I looked and found this: "000000000000a477 T __ZN4CGAL8is_asciiERNSt3__19basic_iosIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEE"

Forgive me but I still don't know how to rectify this. I would greatly appreciate if you could point me in the right direction. Thanks Marc!

Comment: `std::__1::basic_ios` vs `std::basic_ios`. CGAL was compiled using libc++, while you are compiling your example with libstdc++. They are not compatible, so you need to change one of them. Clang has an option `-stdlib=...`.

Comment: Ok this is immensely helpful. I am using the QTCreator IDE, I've been digging around to find out how I can set it to compile with -stdlib=libc++ but so far without success. I will try to find out how I can compile it with the command line. Thank you so much!